# Building a percent of floating rate IRS in QuantLib

Tags: quantlib

Just starting to learn Quantlib for Python.

I am trying to figure out how you create an interest rate swap where the floating leg is a percent of the floating index. For example, the floating leg would be 70% of 1M USD LIBOR.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: For those who are curious, the % of LIBOR swaps are a common structure for municipal entities in the United States. These entities can issue tax-exempt debt and the floating leg is adjusted so the % = (1 - marginal tax rate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to create the swap you want: (1) creating individual legs (`ql.FixedRateLeg` and `IborLeg`) where you can provide a gearing to the `ql.IborLeg` and build a swap (`ql.Swap`) with those or (2) Use the `ql.NonstandardSwap` class

First I'll define the general boilerplate code to use in the examples:

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd

yts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(2, ql.TARGET(), 0.05, ql.Actual360()))
engine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(yts)
index = ql.USDLibor(ql.Period('6M'), yts)

schedule = ql.MakeSchedule(ql.Date(15,6,2021), ql.Date(15,6,2023), ql.Period('6M'))
nominal = [10e6]
```

### 1. Creating individual legs

Before defining a gearing, we can build a simple swap and examine it's floating leg:

```
fixedLeg = ql.FixedRateLeg(schedule, index.dayCounter(), nominal, [0.05])
floatingLeg = ql.IborLeg(nominal, schedule, index)
swap = ql.Swap(fixedLeg, floatingLeg)
swap.setPricingEngine(engine)

print(f"Floating leg NPV: {swap.legNPV(1):,.2f}\n")
pd.DataFrame([{
    'fixingDate': cf.fixingDate().ISO(),
    'accrualStart': cf.accrualStartDate().ISO(),
    'accrualEnd': cf.accrualEndDate().ISO(),
    "paymentDate": cf.date().ISO(),
    'gearing': cf.gearing(),
    'forward': cf.indexFixing(),
    'rate': cf.rate(),
    "amount": cf.amount()
} for cf in map(ql.as_floating_rate_coupon, swap.leg(1))])
```

Notice by default the gearing will be 1 so the leg rate with be the same as the fixing/forwards.

[image]

Next, we use the "gearings" parameter of the `ql.IborLeg` constructor:

```
floatingLeg = ql.IborLeg(nominal, schedule, index, gearings=[0.7])
swap = ql.Swap(fixedLeg, floatingLeg)
swap.setPricingEngine(engine)

print(f"Floating leg NPV: {swap.legNPV(1):,.2f}\n")
pd.DataFrame([{
    'fixingDate': cf.fixingDate().ISO(),
    'accrualStart': cf.accrualStartDate().ISO(),
    'accrualEnd': cf.accrualEndDate().ISO(),
    "paymentDate": cf.date().ISO(),
    'gearing': cf.gearing(),
    'forward': cf.indexFixing(),
    'rate': cf.rate(),
    "amount": cf.amount()
} for cf in map(ql.as_floating_rate_coupon, swap.leg(1))])
```

Notice here, we have ajusted the leg rate to be the fixing/forwards times the gearing.

[image]

Another, a bit more sloppy, way to do it would be to multiply the notional by the gearing on the iborLeg instead of using the gearing parameter.

### 2. NonstandardSwap

The exact same thing can be done with the `ql.NonstandardSwap` class, although you have to be more careful with the constructor as it expects arrays of the notional, rate, spreads, gearings, etc, with the same size as the respective payment schedule.

```
swapType = ql.VanillaSwap.Payer
numDates = (len(schedule)-1)
gearing = [0.7] * numDates
spread = [0.0] * numDates
fixedRateArray = [0.05] * numDates
nominalArray = nominal * numDates
nsSwap = ql.NonstandardSwap(
    swapType, nominalArray, nominalArray,
    schedule, fixedRateArray, index.dayCounter(),
    schedule, index, gearing, spread, index.dayCounter())

nsSwap.setPricingEngine(engine)
print(f"Floating leg NPV: {nsSwap.legNPV(1):,.2f}\n")
pd.DataFrame([{
    'fixingDate': cf.fixingDate().ISO(),
    'accrualStart': cf.accrualStartDate().ISO(),
    'accrualEnd': cf.accrualEndDate().ISO(),
    "paymentDate": cf.date().ISO(),
    'gearing': cf.gearing(),
    'forward': cf.indexFixing(),
    'rate': cf.rate(),
    "amount": cf.amount()
} for cf in map(ql.as_floating_rate_coupon, swap.leg(1))])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed response. I will likely use the non-standard swap as almost all the swaps I would be evaluating are amortizing and so I'll already be working with arrays.

The code mapping into the dataframe is also very helpful. I have the payment schedule so I can use that and compare against the schedule generated by QuantLib.

Answer (score 3):

This feature is called "gearing".

If you look in https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/ql/cashflows/floatingratecoupon.hpp , you see

```c++
Real gearing = 1.0,
```

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283195/

Comment: Much appreciated. For Python, do you know if the gearing setting is only available for the ql.NonstandardSwap instrument? It does not appear to be available to ql.Swap or ql.VanillaSwap.

Comment: As Luigi wrote in his answer, gearing is not exposed in `VanillaSwap` . You may be able to create `FixedLeg` and `IborLeg` (not sure how to say `.withGearings(gearing)` in Python) and pass them both to `Swap`. Or maybe it is not exposed in Python at all. By the way we already saw a SOFR-linked municipal bond with gearing, issued by NY Metropolitan Transportation Authority. https://www.bondbuyer.com/news/mta-deal-leads-municipal-market-into-sofr-era-from-libor

Comment: https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/instruments.html?highlight=Gearing#nonstandardswap the NonStandardSwap could be a solution.